# How to make a miniature of a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div with text and images, and I want to show a miniature of this div in a different place in the page. Any solutions?

Edit:
I want smaller copy of the div, and this should work on IE8, so css3 isn't good solution.

Comment: Do you want to show an image, or a smaller copy of the element?

Comment: What do you mean?  Do you want a smaller version of the content of this div displayed elsewhere?

Comment: You really need to provide a much clearer explanation of what you want or an example

Comment: Show what you've got so far. What have you tried up to this point?

Comment: ok so if you need support for IE8 check my updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). This script allows you to take "screenshots" of webpages or parts of it.

IE8 requires that you include either [FlashCanvas](http://flashcanvas.net/) or [ExplorerCanvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/).

It *might* not be a pixel-perfect representation, but it might get you close.

Once you have your screenshot you should be able to just shrink the canvas (HTML5 canvas, ExplorerCanvas, or FlashCanvas) down to whatever size you need - note: you may run into problems with anti-aliasing and artifacts in the scaled version ... so some additional work may be needed.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
$('#myDiv').clone().appendTo('body').css({'position':'absolute','left':'50px;','top':'300px','transform':'scale(0.5)'})
});
```

**note:**  as they say, you should check under what browser is user and add the vendor (moz, ms, o, webkit, etc ..) to the css property transform

here you can play a bit with it: http://jsfiddle.net/ZPMNz/11/ (with firefox vendor)

---

But if you  need support for ie8, could add a class to the div and declare different styles for it:

```
 $('#myDiv').clone().appendTo('body').addClass('.thumb')});
    });
```

and then you have

```
#myDiv { width:500px;}
#myDiv h1{ font-size:20px;}
#myDiv h2{}
#myDiv p{}

#myDiv.thumb { width:200px;}
#myDiv.thumb h1{ font-size:10px;}
#myDiv.thumb h2{}
#myDiv.thumb p{}
```

it's more work but has more compatibility

Comment: Transform usually require vendor-prefixes, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform.

Comment: Remember the css3 transform property is not supported for ie8 and below.

Comment: utopicam, that would just reduce the size of the container and not the contents.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder so what do you suggest?

Comment: yes it will, but you need the vendor: http://jsfiddle.net/ZPMNz/11/

Comment: utopicam in your case, since you're using chrome, add the `webkit-` prefix to see it in action. Toni, the hard way out would be to change the font-size, the div size and the image size.

Comment: but it does scalle the content, only the vendor prefix is needed

Comment: For IE 8, there is [the `zoom` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531189(VS.85).aspx) (also supported by Safari 4+ and Chrome 2+), which works a bit like `transform:scale();`. See http://jsfiddle.net/QMH7L/ for an example.

Comment: the both div look equal to me :S